# Laravel Eloquent Model change table name on runtime in a related instance

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, has-many, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and also asked the question on Laracast without any success so far.

Here is my problem: I have a database layout something like this:

```
Table: categoryA_products
Table: categoryB_products
Table: categoryC_products
```

and per default the Laravel user table:

```
Table: user
```

I have create a two Laravel Eloquent models:

Product:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    // protected $table = '';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class );
    }

}
```

User:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function products()
        {
            return $this->hasMany( Product::class );
        }
}
```

As each product has a different table name I would normally create 1 model for each table but as they are all similar I would like to define the model table name at runtime.

I know I can do this with "$product->setTable()" but as I use the "newRelatedInstance" class from Laravel (hasMany and belongsTo) I cannot initiate the product class and set the table.

Is there a workaround for this?

Yes, I am aware that I could create a category table and link the products to each category but this is a fictional database model. There is a reason for this approach and I can explain it more in detail if needed. That said it make sense for this sample but I cannot use it for the live database.

I have a working solution with a model for each "*category*" but this is very messy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into Polymophic relationships?

Comment: Yes but I still need a Model for each Category which I try to avoid - unless I miss something on polymorphic realtions

Comment: What's the problem with having a separate model for each `categoryX_product` table? If the same model can be used for all the tables, what's the point of having multiple tables?

Comment: good point. I have around 60 categories which will have a shared relation to a user table but some individual relations to other models which I can extend with traits based on the category. Having 60 models where 90% of the model is the same seems a but redundant to me. That is why I try make this work

Comment: But you could have a product model with the common functionality, and just extend that model for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're unable to load the relations, you could try referencing and re-initializing them like:

```
$relations = $product->getEagerLoads();
$attributes = $product->getOriginal();

table_name = 'categoryA_products'; // or categoryB_products or categoryC_products

$product->newQuery()
        ->newModelInstance($attributes)
        ->setTable($table_name)
        ->setEagerLoads($relations)
        ->...
```